# Why is there nothing in the Materials tab?

Tags: materials

Where'd everything go? I'm just starting with Blender and I thought I was doing everything as in tutorial i watched yesterday, i mean there are like three steps, but clearly something's wrong.
[image]

Comment: Use your right side scroll bar to reveal the "new" option.

Comment: *facepalm* *grunt* ... ok, i'm not awake yet it appears -_____- .... pls delete question.

Comment: [Might be too late to delete question now there is an upvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42265/how-can-i-delete-my-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just scroll up. I know its weird I don't know why it does that.

[image]